# Use Match in sshd_config to detect SCP connection

Tags: ssh

I use the following directive in sshd_config to detect if the user trying to login to a server is called developer, and issue a bash script to the user if that is the case:

```
Match User developer
    ForceCommand /bin/dev_login
```

However, when the user tries to upload a file using SCP, they can't, as the dev_login script is interrupting the process.

Is it possible to use the

```
Match
```

directive to detect if the connection is SCP rather than a request to open a shell?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not. The only arguments to Match are `User`, `Group`, `Host` and `Address`.

I'd recommend using SFTP instead of SCP. The Match commands don't apply to SFTP.